# Get current email's URL Google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

Is there a way for my gmail addon to get access to the current gmail message URL?

I know you can normally do it using `window.location.href` but since you don't have access to the window object from google scripts that doesn't work.

Is there any alternative to do this?

I already searched through the docs many times for something like this but everything is either for spreadsheets or web apps but not for gmail addons.

**Goal:**

When the user submits his message a link to the current email will be added to the message.

[image: example image]

I want to get this URL.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If the user has enabled the conversation the url bar shows the Gmail thread URL. Is this what you want? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].